# Finding a class variable based on another class variable

Tags: c#, class, methods

Let's say that I created a class called Person which has name, year of birth and gender inside of it, for example :

```
class Person{
    public string name;
    public int year;
    public string gender;
    public Person(string _name, int _year, string _gender)
    {
        name= _name;
        year= _year;
        gender= _gender;
    }
}
```

Using that class, I've created 3 people in my main, let's say :

```
     Person person1 = new Person("Bob",1992,"M");

     Person person2 = new Person("Gilbert", 1984, "M");

     Person persone = new Person("hank" 1989, "F");
```

My question is: would it be possible to create a method which takes a year as a parameter and find a person's age and name based on only that?

Here's what I did but it isn't good at all if there is a lot more than only 3 people :

```
public string age(int ParamAge)
{
        string message = "";
        if (ParamAge == 1992)
            message = "Bob is " + (DateTime.Now.Year - ParamAge) + " years old.";
        if (ParamAge == 1984)
            message = "Gilbert is " + (DateTime.Now.Year - ParamAge) + " years old.";
        if (ParamAge == 1989)
            message = "Hank is " + (DateTime.Now.Year - ParamAge) + " years old.";
        return message;
}
```

Comment: put your persons in a list and you can query it quite easily

Comment: What about multiple persons having the same birth year? How do you plan to handle ambiguity?

Comment: Aside from the technical implementation, which I'm sure someone will help you with, do consider that knowing the year someone was born and the current date does not give you enough information to know how old they are, since they could have a birthday (month and day) after the current date or before the current date.

Comment: Put the people in a list. Then use `var person = list.Single(x=> x.Year == year)`. Then use the person instance and do whatever you want.

Comment: Also, if you have two persons with the same birth date, what person will you use?

Comment: I never use `Single()` unless I'm **100%** sure that there is atleast one instance.

Answer (score 1):

You should add all `Person` instances to a `List<Person>`. With linq you can select a person on criteria.

To keep it simple, I used your code:

```
// this is what you know, creating persons.
Person person1 = new Person("Bob","McGee",1992,"M"); // <---- NOTE?   four parameters????  (you code would not compile....)

Person person2 = new Person("Gilbert", 1984, "M");

Person persone = new Person("hank" 1989, "F");

// create a list that contains Persons
List<Person> list = new List<Person>();

// add those persons to the list.
list.Add(person1);
list.Add(person2);
list.Add(persone);

// with the FirstOrDefault() extension method you can select a person.
Person person = personList.FirstOrDefault(item => item.year == year);

// create a message
string message;

// check if the person is a valid instance, because FirstOrDefault will return the default(Person) if none of the persons mathes the criteria. (default == null)
if(person != null)
    message = Person.name + " is " + (DateTime.Now.Year - person.year).TotalYears + " years old.";
else
    message = "Could not find anyone";

// show the message.
MessageBox.Show(message);
```

---

In short you doesn't need to create a Person declaration foreach person you want to add.

for example:

```
list.Add(new Person("Gilbert", 1984, "M"));
```

Comment: It is not so good solution. More optimal solution to put values to dictionary with key year.

Comment: I love dictionaries, but I think thats the next chapter. In this case a Dictionary should not be used, because de year of birth is not unique. You don't want to end up in a `Dictionary<int, List<Person>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of the concern about an accuracy of +/- one year, I would let the class perform the calculation for you.

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public int RelativeAge
        {
            get { return  DateTime.Today.Year - Year; }
        }

        public Person(string name, int year, string gender)
        {
            Name = name;
            Year = year;
            Gender = gender;
        }

        public string AgeStatement()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} is {1} {2} old.", Name, RelativeAge, MakePlural("year", RelativeAge));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add an S to values over one.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="element">Item to be plural</param>
        /// <param name="value"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string MakePlural(string element, int value)
        {
            return element + ((value > 1) ? "s" : "");
        }
    }
```

Here are the tests to validate your result:

```
    [TestClass]
    public class PersonUnitTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestPersonRelativeAge()
        {
            var p = new Person("Jane", 1986, "F");
            Assert.AreEqual(p.RelativeAge, 30);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestAgeStatement()
        {
            var p = new Person("Jane", 1986, "F");
            Assert.AreEqual(p.AgeStatement(), "Jane is 30 years old.");
        }
    }
```